# Any way to send a Tweet as someone else without applying to Twitter Dev again?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

So I applied as a Twitter Dev to make a bot that tweets stuff. About two days later, I got access. When I ran the code with the tokens it gave me, it posts from my account.

My question: Is there a way for me to make it send as another account (a bot account) without me having to apply again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [Sign-in with Twitter flow](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/guides/log-in-with-twitter) to authenticate a different user to your app, and then use the Access Token and Access Token Secret for that user to post to that account. This is the correct way to implement things - you should not be applying for multiple developer accounts.

You can also use tools like twurl or another CLI tool to

- https://github.com/twitter/twurl/
- https://github.com/smaeda-ks/tw-oob-oauth-cli
- https://github.com/olithissen/twitter-oob

Answer (score -1):

Did you get elevated access from tweeter or Essential?  I have a stack error:

```
You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. 
If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal.
```

It's hard to get Elevated now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).